# Is there any maximum font size in docx template for PHPWord to work?

Tags: templates, fonts, size, phpword

I'm using PHPWord to generate a docx file. It works as it is supposed to, I have several tags in the template using the format ${pattern} and the setValue() method works fine with them except with one. This only tag has a 24 font size and rest of them 11 font size, I test setting this tag font size to 11 and it works algo fine.

So, is there any maximum font size for PHPWord to work? If so, how can I make this tag 24 font size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font size like this.

```
// Include the PHPWord.php, all other classes were loaded by an autoloader
require_once 'PHPWord.php';

// Create a new PHPWord Object
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

// Create a section
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

// You can directly style your text by giving the addText function an array:
$section->addText('The text you want to change to font size 24.', array('size'=>24));
```

and then set it back to size 11 when you done.

Comment: As far as I understand sections can be used when you are creating a docx from scratch, I'm working with a template and I don't find the way to make this work